# How does xcode link changes in the interface builder to the actual app (code)?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, storyboard, xcode5

I'm a newbie to ios developement. I'm using storyboards with xcode 5.1, and doing much of my designing using the interface builder.

Firstly, I wanted to know if xcode actually translates the interface builder config into (objective C) code. If yes, can such code be accessed (easily)?

Secondly, when exactly does xcode create the view? Before initwithnibname() or within some of these predefined methods? 
Actually, I wanted to know if for example a button which set as hidden from interface builder will be hidden when viewdidload() is called again at some point in time or not? If not, how can I reinitialise a view programmatically?

Comment: [Good Apple ref](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH4-SW19).  The Nib's loaded at runtime by Apple code, which is objective-C most likely, but like the rest of AppKit/UIKit, you can't see it.  To start to answer the last question, the view's *unarchived*, so it can persist some state.  But it should be view-only state, not model state.

Comment: Thank you for your comment steve. I should start reading more of Apple's refs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- (Firstly) No. It translates the "interface builder config" into *instances*. To put it another way, what's in the nib *are* instances, and you can readily see them:

  ```
  <tableViewCell clearsContextBeforeDrawing="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" selectionStyle="blue" indentationWidth="10" reuseIdentifier="TrackCell" id="2" userLabel="Cell" customClass="MyCell">
      <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="147"/>
      <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
      <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" tableViewCell="2" id="WVn-Ij-tEm">
          <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="146"/>
          <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
          <subviews>
              <label opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" tag="1" contentMode="scaleToFill" text="Zumalama" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" numberOfLines="10" minimumFontSize="10" preferredMaxLayoutWidth="308" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="8" userLabel="LabelTag1">
                  <rect key="frame" x="6" y="3" width="308" height="38"/>
                  <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                  <constraints>
                      <constraint firstAttribute="height" relation="greaterThanOrEqual" constant="21" id="56"/>
                      <constraint firstAttribute="height" priority="1" constant="38" id="95"/>
                  </constraints>
                  <fontDescription key="fontDescription" name="Georgia-Bold" family="Georgia" pointSize="14"/>
                  <color key="textColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                  <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
              </label>
              <!-- and so on ... -->
  ```
- (Secondly) I assume you are talking about a view controller's main view. It creates that view when (i.e. because) it loads the nib containing it, namely, when the view is first needed - either because code refers to it directly or (more usually) because the moment is approaching when it is to be put it into the interface. So, this is some time after `initWithNibName:` - all *that* did was make and prepare a view controller, which is quite a different matter. The moment itself is usually marked by (get this) `viewDidLoad`.
- (Actually) If the nib loads again, you get fresh instances out of the nib, unaffected by anything that happened to any previous instances that came from previous loadings of this nib. Thus loading a nib multiple times is a good way to get fresh pristine copies of a view - as happens, for example, with a table view cell that comes from a nib. But, just the other way, if you push a view controller, pop it, and push it again, all state has been lost, since this is a new instance of this view controller and its view; restoring state, if that is your goal, is up to you.

Comment: And see my full discussion of this topic: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch07.html#_nib_loading_and_file_8217_s_owner

Comment: Thanks a lot for your insightful answer. The link you provided is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @user3490458 I'm glad you are curious about this, and not merely accepting nibs as some kind of magic. They are not at all magic, and understanding them is crucial if you're to use them successfully. Unfortunately, Apple has made this _look_ like magic, causing beginners to fall into all kinds of traps. - You might also look at chapter 19, which discusses view controllers and nib loading in more detail.